# How to build with babel and node 14?

Tags: node.js, babeljs

Im trying to build my project with babel and target node 14.15.4

My .babelrc is like this

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": true
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

So i expected babel output will be compatible with current node. Unfortunately babel output keeps using `require` syntax instead of `import` so can't be run with node 14, that throws error

```
require("./server.js");
^

ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at file:///Users/grzegorz/Projects/charts/server/dist/index.js:3:1
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:152:23)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:166:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
```

Any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: Node 14 can absolutely run code with `require`, you just can't load the files as an ESM module. Please post the full error and elaborate on how you are running your code.

Comment: @loganfsmyth i updated odescirption so you can see full error. Indeed the source is in loading file as en ESM module. However this `require` is there, because babel transpiled `import` incorrectly. I run code by `babel src/ -d dist` and then  `node dist/index.js`.

Comment: You can pass `modules:false` to `preset-env` alongside `targets`. Babel has no way of knowing whether you want the file output in ESM or CommonJS, since Node supports both.

Comment: Thx @loganfsmyth. However, maybe i misunderstood something but in babel docs one can find "you can specify "node": true or "node": "current", which would be the same as "node": process.versions.node". So babel knows i want to build for node 14.15.4 and therefore knows that, require('./server.js') will throw error, but still do this with knowledge that output wont be runnable.

Comment: `require` only throws in Node 14 if you're using ES module `import`. Node 14 didn't stop supporting `require`, but you are using it in a way that disallows `require` and you haven't told Babel that.

Comment: @loganfsmyth but it is not require that throws error. It is node, throwing thay `require` is not defined

Comment: ok there was "type" : "module" in package.json, that was the reason :)

Answer (score 6):

## node

> Type: string | "current" | true.

If you want to compile against the current node version, you can specify "node": true or "node": "current", which would be the same as "node": **process.versions.node**.

*Example:1*

```
{
  "targets": "current"
}
```

*example:2*

```
{
  "targets": true
}
```

*example:3*

```
{
  "targets": "process.versions.node"
}
```

Alternatively, you can specify the node version in a browserslist query:

```
{
  "targets": "node 12" // not recommended
}
```

### Because Node.js may support new language features in minor releases, a program generated for Node.js 12.22 may throw a syntax error on Node.js 12.0. We recommend that you always specify a minor version.

```
{
  "targets": "node 12.0"
}
```

[Info coming from here!](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#targetsnode)

Comment: If targets is specified as an object of minimum environment versions to support, then: "If a minor version is not specified, Babel will interpret it as MAJOR.0. For example, "node": 12 will be considered as Node.js 12.0." - https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#targets

Answer (score 5):

The following will tell babel not to transform modules:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets":{"node":"14"},
        "modules": false,
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Modules code produced in this manor will contain no inter-op glue. `"modules": false` is the key to this. Without it babel is very insistent on trans-piling to CommonJS compatible syntax. This option disables all module syntax transforms. This option drops the comp-ability glue and requires usage.